# How to build this type of query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Please help me build this query.

```
id    description   
101   valueA 
202   valueA 
303   valueA 
404   valueB
```

[table1 and table2] are related via primary key [id]. 
Result should be stored on a table or a temporary table like this.

```
[Table1] 
id     description 
1      valueA 
2      valueB 


[Table2] 
id       ids 
1        101 
1        202 
1        303 
2        404
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, understand that this might be your first question. You might want to check out existing answers to help you with your query. After that, you might want to be more specific with your question as well. Do check out this link: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself? This is not a code writing or tutoring service. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would work for you!

`SELECT
    table2.ids,
    table1.description
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id`

[image]

Comment: No, its the reverse, the table below should be the output.

Comment: these tables should be the output.[Table1] 
id     description 
1      valueA 
2      valueB 


[Table2] 
id       ids 
1        101 
1        202 
1        303 
2        404